# Should I use express, client-side react router or server-side react router?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have a simple app which shows a list of comments by users. When a user is clicked the app should go to `/users/<id>` and show a new page with the users details that will be queried from a MongoDB. Im having trouble to understand where should that logic be.

I saw examples of using the react router in the client like:

```
render((
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
), document.body)
```

But also like this in the server side:

```
<Route name="root" path="/" handler={require('./handlers/Root')}>
```

And also using express routing:

```
app.get('/', function home (req, res, next) {
  res.render('layout', {
    reactHtml: React.renderToString(<App />)
  });
});

app.get('/user', function home (req, res, next) {
  res.render('layout', {
    reactHtml: React.renderToString(<User />)
  });
});
```

Which one is the way to go? What are the differences?

Comment: How did you decide to do this? I'm not sure how React Router and Express are supposed to work together.

Answer (score 2):

React applications are often initially client-side only, attached to the node as you have noticed. This is what makes it so speedy: only API calls, no re-renders.

Isomorphic apps run on the server too, which is helpful for fallback (no JS) and for SEO and social sharing (Facebook needs to read the HTML meta tags. This isn't at all easy to achieve. You can also get really fancy and hydrate from the server rendering, which accelerates the user experience on those deeper pages.

What you will likely never want is to just render server-side. Kind of misses the full power of React.

Start client, with some good boilerplate like https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example which will take you all the way to isomorphic and back again.

Answer (score 0):

With react you make single page applications, so you will never reload the page, with express you're making a server like apache with php

Comment: So you are saying I should just serve a single file with node and then have all of my logic in the client?

Comment: If you choose to make a React application yes

Comment: And how would that approach work with server side rendering? It seems like only the root element will be rendered and from then every thing will be client side